# Not find a item IAP on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I did everything right, here is the iTunesConnect integrated shopping screenshot and my simple code. Only he tells me "no integrated purchase".
I've done it hundreds of times, but I still do not understand it.
My productID fits well on itunes as in the code. So where's the problem ?
Help me please guys :)

Code :

```
#import ....
#import ....

#define kTutorialPointProductID @"com.mathrack.SocialFame.CoinsPlus"

..........
..........


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self fetchAvailableProducts];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; //UIImageNamed:@"transparent.png"
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];////UIImageNamed:@"transparent.png"
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}

-(void)fetchAvailableProducts{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet
                                 setWithObjects:kTutorialPointProductID,nil];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                       initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}
- (void)purchaseMyProduct:(SKProduct*)product{
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                  @"Les achats intégrés sont désactiver sur votre appareil" message:nil delegate:
                                  self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)buy50coins:(id)sender {
    [self purchaseMyProduct:[validProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
}

#pragma mark StoreKit Delegate

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"Purchasing");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                     isEqualToString:kTutorialPointProductID]) {
                    NSLog(@"Purchased ");

                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self purchaseFailed];
                NSLog(@"Purchase failed ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if (count>0) {
        validProducts = response.products;
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([validProduct.productIdentifier
             isEqualToString:kTutorialPointProductID]) {
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:@"Non disponible"
                            message:@"Aucun produit à acheter"
                            delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [tmp show];
    }
}

- (void)purchaseFailed {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                              @"Achat impossible" message:@"Un problème est survenue lors de votre achat, veuillez réessayer ulterieurement" delegate:
                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

ItunesConnect picture :

[image]

Comment: Are you testing on a real device?  Have you completed all of the items under "tax and banking" in App Store Connect?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes is all good, but it does not work

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a contract in process, it surely comes from there

Comment: @Paulw11 It's work, thanks you so much man